# Formula to convert position axis into time

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I have a cube which i am moving in circle shape (with horizontal key input) is below code suggested.

```
public class Oscillator : MonoBehaviour {
    float timeCounter = 0;

    float speed,width, height;

    public float yPosition = 30;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        speed = 2; width = 10; height = 10;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        timeCounter += Time.deltaTime * speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float x = Mathf.Sin (timeCounter)* height; 
        float y = yPosition;
        float z = Mathf.Cos (timeCounter) * width;
        transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y, z);

    }
}
```

Now my object is moving  in circular shape which is fine. Now i want to translate my objects movement into time.
Let suppose

if my object x position is 1 then it should give me time 1.0

if it is 1.5 then it should give me 1.5

it increase or decrease according to x postion of my object (or possibly throught z).

**I logged my object's x position which is starting from 0 to 9.999 and then become decrease 0, then -1 to -9 then it become decrease 0 and reached to its initial position**. This circular movement x values are strange for me, i am unable to form any formula that can convert my x position into time.
Please can any one help me in this purely mathematics and 3d math problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

Get the vector between origin of the circle and the 0 of your circle, like 12 on a clock. This one is constant.

Then you have the vector between the origin of the circle and the current point.

Try the following:

```
Vector3 from = new Vector3(0,0,1); / This is your 12 
Vector3 to = GetCurrentVector();
float angle = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, to - from).eulerAngles.z;
Debug.Log(angle / 360f);
```

Comment: I didn't undertand your answer. what is "to" here