# how to grow a float variable depending on the position of the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to increase or decrease a float variable that is between 1 and 0.4 depending on the position of the mouse.

For example, mouse moves up, value increases, mouse moves down it decreases, but is not greater than 1 or less than 0.4
I know I did not attach any code, but I just want an indication. Thanks
!

Comment: " I know I did not attach any code" But that´s what you should do so we know what you´ve tried and where specifically you´re stuck.

Comment: Well, I've tried several things to link somehow the position of the mouse on the y-axis with this variable, but none of it goes out

Comment: And how should *we* know which attemps didn´t work for you in order to not to write the exact same? I doubt that´ll help you, would it?

Comment: As a hint find minY and maxY of your screen resolution and the get the difference and map this range into your range 0.4 and 1

Comment: Then you can transform every position of your mouse into your "world-coordinates" within the provided range.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to change your mouse position (for example in y-axis) range to your desired range (between 4.0 to 1)

```
public static double ConvertRange(
    double originalStart, double originalEnd, // original range
    double newStart, double newEnd, // desired range
     value) // value to convert
{
    double scale = (double)(newEnd - newStart) / (originalEnd - originalStart);
    return newStart + ((value - originalStart) * scale);
}
```

It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229711/4527628)