# Faster way to convert a number from range to another range

Tags: c++, c, performance, math, optimization

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio), it is possible to convert a number range to another (linear conversion) by calculating:

`NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin`

However, I want to know if there is another **faster** way to do this.

Consider a microcontroller with no division instruction, converting massive amount of a ranges to another ranges (i.e. 24-bit color/pixels from image file to 18-bit color/pixels for the LCD display) would take sometime. I was thinking is there any way to optimze this.

Comment: The only alternative to integer division here is a floating point multiplication. No matter which way you turn, you cannot alter the rules of fundamental math.

Comment: I could imagine floating point operations would be even slower on those devices.

Comment: Your given example of converting range (0,2^24-1) to (0,2^18-1) could be done with a bit shift (plus an add, if you want to round to nearest)

Comment: @DrewDormann Can you give out an example?

Comment: @KongChunHo `NewValue = OldValue >> 6` will drop the 6 least significant bits.  Be sure your values are `unsigned`.

Comment: "Faster way to convert a number from range to another range" --> in general, no.  For select values and sub-ranges, yes.  Yet this code does not post types, nor ranges.  So unclear

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: never say "the only". In this particular case, a simple shift will most probably do. In other cases, fixed-point will be better.

Comment: @DrewDormann: you don't shift the number as a whole ! Rather, you shift every component separately by two bits.

Comment: What's the word length of the microcontroller ?

Answer (score 4):

24 bit color is usually 8 x 3 (3 components, 8 bits per).

18 bit color is 6 x 3.

A simple `>>2` converts the range of 8 bit values to 6 bit values, "rounding down".  And shift operations are fast on most hardware.

Rounding to nearest is harder mainly because of overflow.  Starrt with this:

```
(x+2)>>2
```

in a 16 bit value.  The result is a value from 0 to 2^6, not 0 to 2^6-1 like you want.  You'll have to detect that last case.

If you can afford the ROM, a lookup table can be used.  256 entries isn't all that many.  This may be more worth considering if you want to apply gamma or other corrections.

But really, just `>>2` and/or mask each component, then shift and mask into place.

```
int32 r = ((pix>>2)&(0x3F<<0))|((pix>>4)&(0x3F<<6))|((pix>>6)&(0x3F<<12));
```

Where `pix` is a 32 bit value storing your 24 bit pixel and r stores the 18 bit result.

This kind of optimization requires profiling in as close to a real environment as possible.

Comment: Rounding to nearest isn't a good idea here.  Simply discarding the low two bits results in a uniform transform, where exactly 4 source values map onto 1 destination value, throughout the entire range including ends.

Comment: Why you are just ripping off each 2 MSB (i.e. `&0x3F`)? Wouldn't that make the ratio different?

Comment: @KongChunHo Oops took 6 LSB in each byte, not 6 MSB.  Fixing.