# Numpy fit values between a range

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array in numpy of values within the range: `[0, 255] (ubyte)`  and want to remap it to a new range `[0.0, 1.0](float)`

```
x = [0, 127, 255]
```

should become

```
x = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
```

That post [Convert a number range to another range, maintaining ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio) is very general way how to remap a range, but doesn't explain how to conveniently do it in numpy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a number range to another range, maintaining ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio)

Comment: Just `x / 255.0`

Comment: wow that's easy @jdehesa! I didn't see this answer in any other post though. Don't think this is a duplicate regarding to numpy.

Comment: I had to say , the question title indicate that it is about interpolation

Comment: How would you describe the title then?

Comment: @user1767754 say: converting a range scope with numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just use the `division` `'/'` operand on the array:

This applies the operation `element-wise`, so you can `'divide'` the `array` by `255` which will `map` the values for you, like so:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,127,255], dtype="uint8")
x = x / 255
```

which gives:

```
array([0, 0.49803922, 1])
```

it doesn't give your result of `[0,0.5,1]` because `127` is not half of `255`!

Comment: This code is also wrong! Funny how difficult seems to be just having a division. Aside from `np` not being defined, you will have casting issues because NumPy will think `x` is an array of `int` and then you should not use the `/=` operator but split to `x = x / 255`, which will force automatic type coercion correctly.

Comment: @norok2 sorry! I always run code on my computer then type out the code on SO, I had the lines `import numpy as np` and `np.array([...], dtype="uint8")` which I think will fix both the problems you have picked up. Let me know if you spot anything else wrong as I am new to `numpy` as well. Thank You

Comment: explicit call of the `dtype` will not fix the casting issue, what will is replacing `x /= 255` with `x = x / 255`

Comment: @norok2 I will update the answer. But would appreciate if you could explain further what you mean by a 'casting issue'

Comment: after creation `x` is an array of `int` and if you use the `/=` operator, it will try to calculate the operation in-place. However, the result of `/` cannot be safely casted to `int` (in this case you would get `0` everywhere except where `x == 255` if NumPy wouldn't throw a `TypeError` meanwhile), so what you want to do is to compute `x / 255` separately (which will not happen in-place) and then bind the result again to `x` (which will render the previous array unaccessible).