# convert images from [-1; 1] to [0; 255]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I know that question is really simple, but I didn't find how to bypass the issue:

I'm processing images, the output pixels are *float32*, and values are in range `[-1; 1]`. The thing is, when saving using openCV, all negative data and float values are lost (I only get images with 0 or 1 values)

So I need to convert those images to `[0; 255]` *(Int8)*

I've tried

- `img * 255`, but doing this does not help with negative values.
- `(img + 1) * 255`, I'm removing the negative values, but I'm creating
  an overflow

Is there a (clean) way to do it ?

I'm using Python35, OpenCV2 and Numpy, but I think it's more a math problem than a library thing

Comment: `img + 1` would give you `[0,2]`, you'd then need to multiply by `256/2`.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming your input range might be `[-1,1)`, if not you'll need to handle mapping `1.0 -> 256` causing an overflow.

Comment: You can use `cv2.normalize()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you have found, `img * 255` gives you a resulting range of  `[-255:255]`, and `(img + 1) * 255` gives you a result of `[0:510]`. You're on the right track.

What you need is either: `int((img + 1) * 255 / 2)` or `round((img + 1) * 255 / 2)`. This shifts the input from `[-1:1]` to `[0:2]` then multiplies by `127.5` to get `[0.0:255.0]`.

Using `int()` will actually result in `[0:254]`

Answer (score 30):

You can use `cv2.normalize()`

Consider the following array `a`:

```
a = np.array([[-0.12547205, -1.        ],
              [ 0.49696118,  0.91790167],
              [ 0.81638017,  1.        ]])

norm_image = cv2.normalize(image, None, alpha = 0, beta = 255, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_32F)

norm_image = norm_image.astype(np.uint8)
```

`norm_image` returns the following array:

```
array([[111,   0],
      [190, 244],
      [231, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

In this example:

- `-1` will be mapped to `0`
- `1` will be mpped to `255`
- Everything in between will be mapped accordingly (0, 255)

Points to note:

1. Ensure the array is of type `float`
2. The *extreme* of values are place in `alpha` and `beta` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm marking another response as accepted since it's more general usage (not bound to Opencv). I still appreciate the clear explanation!

Comment: @MelAbgrall Well enough. I gave this answer since this question was tagged to OpenCV :d

Answer (score 4):

If you simply need to map the *range* -1, 1 to the *range* 0, 255 you can simply compare the ranges:

```
OldMin = -1
OldMax = 1
NewMin = 0
NewMax = 255

OldValue = 0.42

OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin)  
NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin)  
NewValue = int((((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin)

print NewValue #OUTPUT: 181
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio) for proper mapping

Comment: Nice ! I had a similar issue with 16Bit images several months ago... OpenCV handle 16 bit images for some operation, So I didn't had to bother... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to map an image from float32 [-1.0, 1.0] to integers [0,255] using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

# sample a GAN image generator in range [-1.0,1.0]
img = generate_images(generator,1)[0] 

# Map interval [-1.0,1.0] to [0.0, 255.0]
img = ((img+1)/2.0)*255

# Convert image type to [0, 255]
img = Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'))
```