# Convert the number to a fraction of specified range

Tags: python, numbers

So Im looking for some smart way to convert **any** number into a fraction. I need to achieve this:

```
0.0001 >= my_number >= 0.00001
```

the problem is that my_number may come as:

```
194619.98341
```

as well as:

```
0.00231134
```

(examples) so it is possibly any number greater than 0. Im struggling to create a function which will convert it so it belongs to the specified range.

Comment: The [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module exists, and while it will "convert any number into a fraction", I'm not sure what you're asking so I'm not sure how appropriate it is for what you're trying to do.  But it may be worth looking in to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a number range to another range, maintaining ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was not that hard:

```
if x > 0.00001:
    while not 0.0001 >= x >= 0.00001:
        x = x / 10
else:
    while not 0.0001 >= x >= 0.00001:
        x = x * 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of numbers and you want them all to be included in this specified range, what you can do is:

```
def scale(numbers, low_bound, high_bound):
    return [(x - min(numbers)) / (max(numbers) - min(numbers)) * (high_bound - low_bound) + low_bound for x in numbers]
```

Now, if you it:

```
list = [1209.76671, 0.9831, 0.000009873, 123]
scale(list, 0.00001, 0.0001)

# which gives:
# [0.0001, 1.0073136507576801e-05, 1e-05, 1.9150523907020985e-05]
```

Note that this will always set the minimum of the list of numbers to 0.00001 and always set the maximum to 0.0001.

Now, I don't know if this answers your question so please tell me if I'm mistaken in interpreting your question...