# re-mapping a number to another range in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

How can I re-map a number from one range to another in pygame or python ?

eg: If I want to map to map x=25 with range 0-100 to a new range from 0-20.. the new value of x would be 5.

Comment: You could look here for an idea of how to implement re-ranging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function which maps from a range [a, b] to a range [c, d]:

```py
def maprange(x, a, b, c, d):
    w =  (x-a) / (b-a)
    y = c + w * (d-c)
    return y
```

```py
y = maprange(25, 0, 100, 0, 20)
```