# Scaling a number between a certain range to that of another in python

Tags: python, range, scale

Is there a method by which a number between the range of lets say (a, b) can be scaled to a different range of lets say (p, q)?

In my case, I have a number between in the range of 0 to 1 i.e (0, 1) and wanna scale it such that it lies in the range of -1 to 1 i.e.(-1, 1).

Example -:

```
# 1 will remain 1 if scaled.
scale(1, (0, 1), (-1, 1)) # => Returns 1
# 0.5 will be scaled to 0.
scale(0.5, (0, 1), (-1, 1)) # => Returns 0
# 0 will be scaled to -1.
scale(0, (0, 1), (-1, 1)) # => Returns -1
```

I was able to find a few related threads on -:
[Based on mathematical formula and does not mention any pythonic way of doing so and secondly I am not able to distinguish between the upper and lower limits and max(x), min(x)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178626/how-to-normalize-data-between-1-and-1)

Comment: What kind of range is `(1, -1)`??? Should be `(min, max)`, not `(max, min)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a number range to another range, maintaining ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio)

Comment: No since its not for python ig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def scale(x, srcRange, dstRange):
    return (x-srcRange[0])*(dstRange[1]-dstRange[0])/(srcRange[1]-srcRange[0])+dstRange[0]
```

Of course, each range must be given in the form of `(min, max)`.

In your example, one of the ranges is given the form of `(max, min)`.

Comment: Yup sry I did not notice that I will edit the range to min, max

Comment: Yes this works Thanks for the answer can you explain a little bit on how this works?