# Compress a range number by two max percent and min percent

Tags: function, math

Let's say I have a range like 100-1. Now, I want to compress that range by 10% on the top, and 25% from the bottom. So my final range would be 90-25.

Any ideas on how to make a function that given any number from 100 to 1 are transformed to the 90-25 range?

Comment: Solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio

Comment: Ah okay, finally I understand your question now :-D to me it was missing that you want to keep ratios in between and not just "throw away all outside the new range". Thanks for linking to that one!

Comment: I didn't explain myself properly. My bad.

Comment: no worries - glad you find a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

Let `u` be the upper number (in your example: 100) and `l` be the lower number (example: 1), so you want to transform the interval/range/... `[1, 100]` to a shrinked one.

With usual math knowledge one sees that removing some percent from the bottom/top is the same as just moving that number, so in your case you would want to use the interval `[l * 0.25, u * 0.9]` instead of `[l, u]`. This generalizes to all other values of course.

In case you don't want rational numbers but only integers, you'll have to think about whether you want to shrink *more* or *less* than 25/10% because you can't be exact then.

Using this new interval now you can create that function using pseudocode:

```
def transform(n, lower, upper):
    interval = [lower * 0.25, upper * 0.9]
    if n in interval:
        return n
    else if n < lower * 0.25:
        return lower * 0.25
    else if n > upper * 0.9:
        return  upper * 0.9
```

Comment: In your example is not clear to me how to make the transformation of a number. My functions should be something like `transform(n, u=0.1, l=0.25)` If n is 1 the output should be 25 but if n is 100 the output should be 90.

Comment: ah okay, now I think I understand, that was not clear to me from the question. So e.g. 50 should be outputted 50 then? EDIT: updated the code.