# Large Datsample: failing to better visualize data point using matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, genetic-programming

The size of the data samples is very large, making it difficult to visualise the data points using a matplotlib plot.

**Sample Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(myList_timestamps, myList_fitnessValues)
plt.xlabel('Timestamps (seconds)')
#plt.xticks(range(1, 51)
#plt.xticks(range(1, 53, 5))
plt.ylabel('WATT - MSU Fitness Values')
plt.title('Evolutionary Optimization - Execution Time')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

I have `9113 candidates solutions` as data samples to plot against `9113 data samples as fitness values`. **How should I plot this large data using python to better visualize the data?**

**Data Sample:**

```
myList_timestamps = [[0.06160092353820801,
 0.07070684432983398,
 0.0794517993927002,
 0.08730483055114746,
 0.09506797790527344,
 0.10278487205505371,
 0.11050796508789062,
 0.11819696426391602,
 0.12598776817321777,
 0.13364410400390625,
 0.1412339210510254,
 0.14882898330688477,
 0.15642499923706055,
 0.16405892372131348,
 0.171644926071167,
 0.17924880981445312,
 0.1868269443511963,
 0.1943988800048828,
 0.2020108699798584,
 0.21060776710510254,
 0.219498872756958,
 0.22813701629638672,
 0.23638296127319336,
 0.24529194831848145,
 0.25347185134887695,
 0.26166296005249023,
 0.2696189880371094,
 0.2773740291595459,
 0.2849307060241699,
 0.2925240993499756,
 0.30014586448669434,
 0.3077728748321533,
 0.31533288955688477,
 0.32283592224121094,
 0.3303370475769043,
 0.3378570079803467,
 0.34534668922424316,
 0.352841854095459,
 0.36031174659729004,
 0.3678579330444336,
 0.3753628730773926,
 0.3828439712524414,
 0.3903648853302002,
 0.39795589447021484,
 0.40547990798950195,
 0.412992000579834,
 0.42046594619750977,
 0.42803382873535156,
 0.435579776763916,
 0.44308996200561523,
 0.450577974319458,
 0.45802807807922363,
 0.4655318260192871,
 0.4730229377746582,
 0.48052191734313965,
 0.488048791885376,
 0.49558186531066895,
 0.5031087398529053,
 0.5106048583984375,
 0.5181560516357422,
 0.525662899017334,
 0.5331556797027588,
 0.5406389236450195,
 0.5481007099151611,
 0.5555720329284668,
 0.563060998916626,
 0.5705769062042236,
 0.578115701675415,
 0.5856177806854248,
 0.5931298732757568,
 0.6006178855895996,
 0.6081528663635254,
 0.6156718730926514,
 0.6231448650360107,
 0.6306188106536865,
 0.6381428241729736,
 0.6456358432769775,
 0.6531088352203369,
 0.6606647968292236,
 0.6682088375091553,
 0.6756858825683594,
 0.6832168102264404,
 0.6907000541687012,
 0.6981749534606934,
 0.7056229114532471,
 0.7130780220031738,
 0.7205479145050049,
 0.728065013885498,
 0.7355530261993408,
 0.743027925491333,
 0.7505538463592529,
 0.7580459117889404,
 0.7654819488525391,
 0.7729947566986084,
 0.7804989814758301,
 0.7879579067230225,
 0.7954659461975098,
 0.8029458522796631,
 0.8104219436645508,
 0.8179588317871094,
 0.8254818916320801,
 0.8329558372497559,
 0.840451717376709,
 0.8479418754577637,
 0.8554189205169678,
 0.8629167079925537,
 0.8704218864440918,
 0.8782069683074951,
 0.8857617378234863,
 0.8933010101318359,
 0.9008169174194336,
 0.9083929061889648,
 0.9159009456634521,
 0.923414945602417,
 0.9309487342834473,
 0.9386038780212402,
 0.9461567401885986,
 0.9536347389221191,
 0.9610898494720459,
 0.9685368537902832,
 0.9759769439697266,
 0.983414888381958,
 0.9908480644226074,
 0.9982888698577881,
 1.0057227611541748,
 1.01314377784729,
 1.0205698013305664,
 1.0280189514160156,
 1.035449743270874,
 1.0429389476776123,
 1.0503628253936768,
 1.0578010082244873,
 1.0658130645751953,
 1.0734107494354248,
 1.081054925918579,
 1.0888869762420654,
 1.0964579582214355,
 1.1040010452270508,
 1.1115117073059082,
 1.1190118789672852,
 1.1264939308166504,
 1.1339750289916992,
 1.141474723815918,
 1.1489946842193604,
 1.156526803970337,
 1.164029836654663,
 1.1716160774230957,
 1.1790966987609863,
 1.1865930557250977,
 1.1940937042236328,
 1.2019388675689697,
 1.2094628810882568,
 1.216930866241455,
 1.2243878841400146,
 1.2318336963653564,
 1.2393128871917725,
 1.2467608451843262,
 1.2542097568511963,
 1.2619950771331787,
 1.2704198360443115,
 1.2786128520965576,
 1.2871167659759521,
 1.2947309017181396,
 1.302293062210083,
 1.309783697128296,
 1.3177897930145264,
 1.3256456851959229,
 1.3331577777862549,
 1.340836763381958,
 1.348417043685913,
 1.355942964553833,
 1.3635058403015137,
 1.3709850311279297,
 1.3785638809204102,
 1.3860559463500977,
 1.3935277462005615,
 1.4009969234466553,
 1.408479928970337,
 1.415954828262329,
 1.423440933227539,
 1.4309158325195312,
 1.4383947849273682,
 1.4458889961242676,
 1.453355073928833,
 1.4608356952667236,
 1.468317985534668,
 1.4757959842681885,
 1.4833028316497803,
 1.4908149242401123,
 1.4983007907867432,
 1.505788803100586,
 1.5132827758789062,
 1.520780086517334,
 1.5282917022705078,
 1.5357389450073242,
 1.5432488918304443,
 1.5507168769836426,
 1.5581979751586914,
 1.565687656402588,
 1.5731756687164307,
 1.58066987991333,
 1.5881669521331787,
 1.5956358909606934,
 1.6031649112701416,
 1.6106679439544678,
 1.6181929111480713,
 1.6265389919281006,
 1.634814977645874,
 1.6424179077148438,
 1.6499037742614746,
 1.657348871231079,
 1.6648588180541992,
 1.6722848415374756,
 1.6797456741333008,
 1.6871848106384277,
 1.6946487426757812,
 1.7022688388824463,
 1.7098469734191895,
 1.7173528671264648,
 1.724863052368164,
 1.73232102394104,
 1.7397880554199219,
 1.7472498416900635,
 1.7546827793121338,
 1.762143850326538,
 1.7696146965026855,
 1.777108907699585,
 1.7845828533172607,
 1.7920348644256592,
 1.7994859218597412,
 1.806952953338623,
 1.8144299983978271,
 1.8218896389007568,
 1.8293559551239014,
 1.8368110656738281,
 1.8442790508270264,
 1.851726770401001,
 1.8592119216918945,
 1.86667799949646,
 1.8741397857666016,
 1.8815827369689941,
 1.8890256881713867,
 1.8964788913726807,
 1.9039208889007568,
 1.911383867263794,
 1.918832778930664,
 1.9262988567352295,
 1.9337799549102783,
 1.94124174118042,
 1.948828935623169,
 1.9562938213348389,
 1.9637949466705322,
 1.9712047576904297,
 1.9786548614501953,
 1.986097812652588,
 1.9935338497161865,
 2.000976800918579,
 2.0084168910980225,
 2.016091823577881,
 2.023655891418457,
 2.031132936477661,
 2.038616895675659,
 2.0460739135742188,
 2.053546905517578,
 2.060973882675171,
 2.0684218406677246,
 2.0758438110351562,
 2.083289861679077,
 2.0906968116760254,
 2.0981409549713135,
 2.1055638790130615,
 2.1129748821258545,
 2.1203808784484863,
 2.1278228759765625,
 2.1352219581604004,
 2.1426548957824707,
 2.1502327919006348,
 2.1577627658843994,
 2.165205955505371,
 2.1726489067077637,
 2.180156946182251,
 2.1876187324523926,
 2.195056915283203,
 2.202542781829834,
 2.210002899169922,
 2.217458963394165,
 2.2249059677124023,
 2.232353925704956,
 2.2398228645324707,
 2.247271776199341,
 2.2547237873077393,
 2.262202739715576,
 2.269657850265503,
 2.277296781539917,
 2.284979820251465,
 2.2924628257751465,
 2.2999508380889893,
 2.3074228763580322,
 2.3148908615112305,
 2.3223717212677,
 2.329817771911621,
 2.3372578620910645,
 2.34472393989563,
 2.3521809577941895,
 2.359632968902588,
 2.367115020751953,
 2.374567985534668,
 2.382063865661621,
 2.38950777053833,
 2.3970019817352295,
 2.404465913772583,
 2.4119558334350586,
 2.4194018840789795,
 2.4268767833709717,
 2.4343249797821045,
 2.441788911819458,
 2.4492337703704834,
 2.45668888092041,
 2.4641637802124023,
 2.471620798110962,
 2.479109764099121,
 2.48657488822937,
 2.494025945663452,
 2.501471996307373,
 2.508949041366577,
 2.5164427757263184,
 2.523920774459839,
 2.531388998031616,
 2.53886079788208,
 2.5463309288024902,
 2.5537829399108887,
 2.5612847805023193,
 2.568727731704712,
 2.576223850250244,
 2.583711862564087,
 2.591172933578491,
 2.598625898361206,
 2.6060757637023926,
 2.6135129928588867,
 2.621011972427368,
 2.628448963165283,
 2.635972738265991,
 2.643435001373291,
 2.650902032852173,
 2.6583468914031982,
 2.665862798690796,
 2.673314094543457,
 2.680816888809204,
 2.688267946243286,
 2.6957550048828125,
 2.7032127380371094,
 2.7106738090515137,
 2.7181079387664795,
 2.725554943084717,
 2.732996940612793,
 2.740450859069824,
 2.747886896133423,
 2.7553389072418213,
 2.7627639770507812,
 2.7702107429504395,
 2.777662992477417,
 2.7851169109344482,
 2.7925288677215576,
 2.80000376701355,
 2.8074288368225098,
 2.8148789405822754,
 2.8223319053649902,
 2.8297858238220215,
 2.8372128009796143,
 2.84466290473938,
 2.852128028869629,
 2.85958194732666,
 2.8670127391815186,
 2.8744797706604004,
 2.8819189071655273,
 2.8893797397613525,
 2.896803855895996,
 2.9042470455169678,
 2.911679983139038,
 2.919153928756714,
 2.9266068935394287,
 2.9340579509735107,
 2.9415018558502197,
 2.9490177631378174,
 2.9564428329467773,
 2.9638688564300537,
 2.9712448120117188,
 2.9786460399627686,
 2.986050844192505,
 2.9934427738189697,
 3.0008530616760254,
 3.0082297325134277,
 3.015631914138794,
 3.023007869720459,
 3.030390977859497,
 3.0377516746520996,
 3.04512882232666,
 3.052503824234009,
 3.0598559379577637,
 3.067525863647461,
 3.074979782104492,
 3.082453966140747,
 3.089857816696167,
 3.0973098278045654,
 3.104733943939209,
 3.1121609210968018,
 3.11958384513855,
 3.1270148754119873,
 3.1344220638275146,
 3.141826868057251,
 3.1492297649383545,
 3.1566479206085205,
 3.1641108989715576,
 3.1720409393310547,
 3.18062686920166,
 3.188631772994995,
 3.19647479057312,
 3.2040579319000244,
 3.211491823196411,
 3.2189619541168213,
 3.2264137268066406,
 3.2338807582855225,
 3.241302013397217,
 3.248771905899048,
 3.256213903427124,
 3.263671875,
 3.2710888385772705,
 3.2785208225250244,
 3.285946846008301,
 3.293437957763672,
 3.3010239601135254,
 3.3086907863616943,
 3.3162219524383545,
 3.3237030506134033,
 3.3311376571655273,
 3.3386118412017822,
 3.3460726737976074,
 3.3535208702087402,
 3.3609509468078613,
 3.368414878845215,
 3.3758559226989746,
 3.3833189010620117,
 3.3907477855682373,
 3.3982179164886475,
 3.405695915222168,
 3.413137912750244,
 3.420606851577759,
 3.4280447959899902,
 3.435490846633911,
 3.4429378509521484,
 3.4504079818725586,
 3.4578518867492676,
 3.4652678966522217,
 3.4726951122283936,
 3.4801628589630127,
 3.4876327514648438,
 3.4950459003448486,
 3.502520799636841,
 3.5099668502807617,
 3.5174667835235596,
 3.5249149799346924,
 3.532382011413574,
 3.5398058891296387,
 3.547271966934204,
 3.554724931716919,
 3.5621488094329834,
 3.5695910453796387,
 3.5770299434661865,
 3.5844788551330566,
 3.5919089317321777,
 3.599360942840576,
 3.6068217754364014,
 3.6142799854278564,
 3.6217379570007324,
 3.6291840076446533,
 3.636641025543213,
 3.6440939903259277,
 3.651533842086792,
 3.658979892730713,
 3.6664540767669678,
 3.67389178276062,
 3.681334972381592,
 3.688839912414551,
 3.6963768005371094,
 3.7038447856903076,
 3.711305856704712,
 3.718761920928955,
 3.726195812225342,
 3.7336368560791016,
 3.741126775741577,
 3.7485568523406982,
 3.7559916973114014,
 3.763450860977173,
 3.770900011062622,
 3.778341770172119,
 3.785810947418213,
 3.7932307720184326,
 3.800668954849243,
 3.808100938796997,
 3.8155479431152344,
 3.82303786277771,
 3.8304550647735596,
 3.8379018306732178,
 3.845344066619873,
 3.852766990661621,
 3.860213041305542,
 3.867640733718872,
 3.8750839233398438,
 3.8825418949127197,
 3.8900070190429688,
 3.897446870803833,
 3.9049458503723145,
 3.9123809337615967,
 3.919834852218628,
 3.927325963973999,
 3.934762954711914,
 3.9422247409820557,
 3.9497127532958984,
 3.957167863845825,
 3.9645960330963135,
 3.972066879272461,
 3.9795138835906982,
 3.9869298934936523,
 3.9943947792053223,
 4.001836776733398,
 4.0092689990997314,
 4.016718864440918,
 4.0241899490356445,
 4.031642913818359,
 4.039106845855713,
 4.046592950820923,
 4.05404806137085,
 4.061479806900024,
 4.068920850753784,
 4.076357841491699,
 4.083805799484253,
 4.0912556648254395,
 4.098691701889038,
 4.106162786483765,
 4.1136109828948975,
 4.121060848236084,
 4.128498792648315,
 4.135960817337036,
 4.143415689468384,
 4.15084171295166,
 4.158272981643677,
 4.16582989692688,
 4.173282861709595,
 4.180737733840942,
 4.188170909881592,
 4.195602893829346,
 4.203077793121338,
 4.210502862930298,
 4.2179529666900635,
 4.225406885147095,
 4.232857704162598,
 4.240309000015259,
 4.247731924057007,
 4.255206823348999,
 4.262646913528442]
```

```
myList_fitnessValues = [1.177397872785327,
 1.1838368070851042,
 1.198426283830517,
 1.1971495165606483,
 1.1300637485336795,
 1.2187992912454821,
 1.2145353817939883,
 1.0729413153620015,
 1.2521284084941269,
 1.2183068116189408,
 1.195634989638366,
 1.1613388860470966,
 1.2217006054348303,
 1.206234560770683,
 1.2372446068751055,
 1.187058775523,
 1.1872546511295015,
 1.1966112517544802,
 1.2145107120984742,
 1.2421864845871378,
 1.1890153127520433,
 1.1674951340729436,
 1.2251505016710167,
 1.1958552931582382,
 1.2080607542394712,
 1.201035514597457,
 1.092659066061191,
 1.2306418318602446,
 1.1995437445068218,
 1.2449192292367206,
 1.2106208502011808,
 1.2112721352650087,
 1.1196669840676667,
 1.1134332262454683,
 1.1197768644022856,
 1.2261263457543805,
 1.231366828628176,
 1.2196350828703688,
 1.08741318320004,
 1.2032137535738274,
 1.2024228903569536,
 1.2137572975032105,
 1.0738592164216931,
 1.1738526733756591,
 1.1544974613440897,
 1.160844467172908,
 1.2187677280979918,
 1.162505454897613,
 1.2021549705530339,
 1.229063908531223,
 1.214924462090727,
 1.1411833735549284,
 1.1883797211741252,
 1.1342311436728563,
 1.2194421521815677,
 1.1237953059433416,
 1.185322478323287,
 1.1688528378709393,
 1.138039592406455,
 1.1855580350049484,
 1.2303222163698007,
 1.2140360262028758,
 1.09912727836326,
 1.0982013456663848,
 1.2074961979865895,
 1.2130674992213648,
 1.1064772919391566,
 1.2183787053226458,
 1.2387016873859218,
 1.1316362444070998,
 1.0955985789217237,
 1.2295510887027803,
 1.2321228706728062,
 1.2291667095487586,
 1.1943183790667353,
 1.1806877475400122,
 1.0821097661565597,
 1.1885871916833606,
 1.2287827776186633,
 1.1245075536475073,
 1.246567313324614,
 1.1968924804246073,
 1.2357189468661003,
 1.0798212767853532,
 1.210981845170037,
 1.1949578119730175,
 1.0745447494722138,
 1.1842984199966768,
 1.1885233082136473,
 1.1404877293427729,
 1.176750616683678,
 1.2322331744279031,
 1.2008328893267939,
 1.1839763301938666,
 1.1740540064695157,
 1.1215709455350205,
 1.1838699168837248,
 1.2190806980658488,
 1.2187178223617976,
 1.188198435991883,
 1.2420874742392598,
 1.1936975325903234,
 1.145645140863139,
 1.1896439998849606,
 1.0901724022621744,
 1.2214054198855253,
 1.202183913330283,
 1.2214232388980968,
 1.2451547757149166,
 1.1542504637802762,
 1.2150818383252948,
 1.1551718106916113,
 1.180265276583371,
 1.2259447669065064,
 1.23970172148869,
 1.2195702465867029,
 1.2121212076750423,
 1.1196861951049026,
 1.084233317578786,
 1.2184195145467944,
 1.2019297900082373,
 1.2197546777584807,
 1.1806877475400122,
 1.1935874583246553,
 1.1947324698675565,
 1.1949174251388859,
 1.1859323990481676,
 1.0906342354229615,
 1.1176255050944655,
 1.1496417617749741,
 1.214221309853014,
 1.1871680736265695,
 1.1915179673491303,
 1.2025838867023781,
 1.197499571598236,
 1.1366803103334713,
 1.2085395261620986,
 1.211657983876409,
 1.2119904284994945,
 1.1499635839213362,
 1.2048809684531807,
 1.18988003425591,
 1.162958419973022,
 1.2117707427085584,
 1.1243944753618493,
 1.1744385678325748,
 1.1903600159926122,
 1.2016224458259388,
 1.211296343777177,
 1.1349759574949243,
 1.0718396654449382,
 1.1964735952940981,
 1.2321228706728062,
 1.240538488513929,
 1.137008792662425,
 1.118080518441783,
 1.2179995323083854,
 1.2332167673456187,
 1.2299392260321718,
 1.229455434517842,
 1.0945646172721897,
 1.1684574384092985,
 1.2216592587636825,
 1.1473954661560457,
 1.0972316717042851,
 1.2069927716927877,
 1.145655054243576,
 1.1709533542017871,
 1.2399276594736448,
 1.0571702762640665,
 1.1289925835126173,
 1.1978661608433139,
 1.1751549861474675,
 1.189320827332064,
 1.114652077172573,
 1.0855461561951376,
 1.114545327811882,
 1.213725567748654,
 1.20353452440095,
 1.1820774536021856,
 1.186462718947463,
 1.1889690769217898,
 1.2018835746505774,
 1.211090224753304,
 1.1831781914671817,
 1.1773466438721967,
 1.197092394238814,
 1.2041535500147282,
 1.163132237400184,
 1.168563226082197,
 1.1678829662040073,
 1.1363664937760698,
 1.1083990267935506,
 1.2031778809291547,
 1.0676216251859287,
 1.2177599264089978,
 1.0990307312997643,
 1.21049553896777,
 1.1599270669137582,
 1.2328076437831437,
 1.0972099959852455,
 1.2158413254752458,
 1.1858591862647971,
 1.160354488282236,
 1.1885987402151457,
 1.242744809392655,
 1.180804379621974,
 1.1948754664090295,
 1.1999708176480794,
 1.0863273779101585,
 1.1865571118556641,
 1.2247520706088966,
 1.1902065318111597,
 1.1769933798289114,
 1.1908864309517615,
 1.2057410331253477,
 1.2364890730379687,
 1.1663675183275037,
 1.1088393200653563,
 1.20706966917313,
 1.2442896235721,
 1.1069454133505705,
 1.2628901213116968,
 1.1207013243831028,
 1.1582247278576716,
 1.0708548471205084,
 1.2155678255250282,
 1.1986370029163065,
 1.1459855041681286,
 1.2054266674604792,
 1.192257639008284,
 1.197672089140054,
 1.198202892392417,
 1.1025040708024108,
 1.121321746966252,
 1.2149674581109837,
 1.2123920496821512,
 1.227103878165898,
 1.189101851528379,
 1.253525044950779,
 1.2498189114548643,
 1.173845452730351,
 1.2083118238298576,
 1.2030549929175092,
 1.2271213348837007,
 1.1478325884552891,
 1.1960780932197772,
 1.1902259956766275,
 1.2467831992009593,
 1.0792760733500293,
 1.1869221700876043,
 1.0824793309140637,
 1.1955662830576248,
 1.1080499423655457,
 1.2006240107240815,
 1.0880807583848786,
 1.2157448455744477,
 1.1521531149930204,
 1.240280892270902,
 1.1238415805874602,
 1.1828435837181859,
 1.1712592947196425,
 1.2137283926841305,
 1.2424701024482705,
 1.2263538380098462,
 1.2070290285031617,
 1.1631224185724471,
 1.0794787639871248,
 1.093670630714558,
 1.1265887464291346,
 1.2318408943741077,
 1.1936771541321396,
 1.2169441544187152,
 1.198506382581772,
 1.186458880174174,
 1.2103524823669856,
 1.2285778509901992,
 1.1200216208405227,
 1.1387896672101574,
 1.0908173539816957,
 1.2308851210556966,
 1.2035466664307617,
 1.1001905414241768,
 1.1424185494658932,
 1.2269161990482325,
 1.1999656325314627,
 1.1967207679880325,
 1.1600771097377474,
 1.2069027992929418,
 1.1385148138423051,
 1.1489017335157772,
 1.1068267732858115,
 1.2205880980904533,
 1.218044294574066,
 1.2529730847546638,
 1.186660925630313,
 1.2060697606531923,
 1.2045284746581517,
 1.1642166388713013,
 1.1103498769950435,
 1.1756364918041724,
 1.1065195117330475,
 1.185722908999943,
 1.2160505306065248,
 1.1583256484574564,
 1.1826392418072076,
 1.178493074752072,
 1.1177123697895326,
 1.2412795138296302,
 1.2170991263240316,
 1.1378564491277,
 1.2598329438516054,
 1.1594168596923815,
 1.067412768958962,
 1.0681905031107433,
 1.1088495388520627,
 1.2260312346475448,
 1.1845181121770647,
 1.0908462423974803,
 1.2254157975354272,
 1.1726057354383534,
 1.2463105895418234,
 1.1938360058317639,
 1.1809949387357708,
 1.214965669951487,
 1.1806096453015262,
 1.2120442182541238,
 1.2039396191666214,
 1.2241011795101584,
 1.1835653941636586,
 1.1872311824740118,
 1.2049867769183018,
 1.1032492996465715,
 1.2459948771640978,
 1.210714791333494,
 1.2017638381896383,
 1.2082205245581055,
 1.2100706475737704,
 1.1777593480571773,
 1.2463816959419804,
 1.1956288937602344,
 1.2250384673113388,
 1.2232925845822948,
 1.2271097732217437,
 1.2041158407114751,
 1.1731142176012719,
 1.089562181699617,
 1.2065580430236436,
 1.1286176112592208,
 1.214260708902002,
 1.100397749837259,
 1.1634968104491086,
 1.2031492654249205,
 1.241916873584268,
 1.128692464375822,
 1.2438405074344832,
 1.221942545955605,
 1.2122284632985285,
 1.2196872139542247,
 1.1963958742294165,
 1.211163602848183,
 1.1876392875222728,
 1.1120181290701372,
 1.1928622611586417,
 1.2310597744441403,
 1.0909886287400576,
 1.1746761873370748,
 1.086400046407615,
 1.1948938617215121,
 1.237389733833963,
 1.2002584041594944,
 1.1634829773569397,
 1.1560999466513606,
 1.1517515881362235,
 1.18561959209192,
 1.1243333063590204,
 1.168110787112396,
 1.252233283674239,
 1.1809616018853473,
 1.1172192014427276,
 1.065718486758231,
 1.1735702052275503,
 1.2319344426459806,
 1.2406551834164845,
 1.134545708488982,
 1.212394683299605,
 1.0839740327133316,
 1.154921467945748,
 1.1868420784058569,
 1.27846759456701,
 1.1337877151557247,
 1.2090680051988998,
 1.111959785928736,
 1.2162877159119596,
 1.2617090658101289,
 1.0746368205192902,
 1.082494892236285,
 1.12003079427392,
 1.2349350980294647,
 1.2079171758399385,
 1.1540805938938137,
 1.1904244522100265,
 1.0925561509117376,
 1.1130713817081679,
 1.1996791615125522,
 1.1953376557177446,
 1.1721740496775683,
 1.1498018407550115,
 1.2189399864150035,
 1.2174001512005672,
 1.1841444791371007,
 1.185707384067646,
 1.1818600419697818,
 1.1487639315280984,
 1.187990790473883,
 1.2070236352846957,
 1.183120704393338,
 1.2131486529878408,
 1.2230034850431808,
 1.2598577318052009,
 1.222494513225296,
 1.1989335894352298,
 1.133213715468035,
 1.137460808129861,
 1.24270509873175,
 1.1877173094601927,
 1.2104442602106054,
 1.2230272768431958,
 1.1848372792316968,
 1.1892502628879684,
 1.2035024239408367,
 1.1289245106213106,
 1.1547680583390754,
 1.1817062724464646,
 1.07460992973405,
 1.2424105540969468,
 1.2006706347201768,
 1.1469299638380548,
 1.2003475049998125,
 1.2628425996056627,
 1.1704529581521437,
 1.2318309803876157,
 1.0800513855721836,
 1.228251341459926,
 1.20519927398022,
 1.2026116263341706,
 1.2267213579299914,
 1.1944767555176976,
 1.0973340714559194,
 1.199844572870176,
 1.2167600163050747,
 1.1973706771935049,
 1.1274929727743968,
 1.1847494081385286,
 1.2179786952027045,
 1.2103068524172256,
 1.1648972358845942,
 1.2012871447601516,
 1.0806169290790832,
 1.0638847843439245,
 1.1523924483632424,
 1.2163186571317048,
 1.2318610477915777,
 1.1790869269637845,
 1.1800511479858375,
 1.1828738610906249,
 1.1414027009085952,
 1.2239157840282788,
 1.2163662161977793,
 1.0777765284762604,
 1.1871756186016387,
 1.191419398750568,
 1.2077786982792487,
 1.1306928350191163,
 1.2219862084208202,
 1.1704952108872595,
 1.1350341511093405,
 1.2382530787288621,
 1.197672089140054,
 1.1634636863060297,
 1.2198105693727255,
 1.1738029086162305,
 1.1866104828955661,
 1.2050422293564858,
 1.0986376515523584,
 1.1639928343093937,
 1.22645365263098,
 1.0831783532562473,
 1.1793732758175444,
 1.2095496760640134,
 1.1933309580469191,
 1.0970298786458046,
 1.1494963511728211,
 1.1967270644046457,
 1.2344818441993706,
 1.2272379509433546,
 1.1112370068652921,
 1.221504646323395,
 1.2374620707520216,
 1.1180642101127265,
 1.2499150575244404,
 1.1306307576694052,
 1.2043884061922128,
 1.2148802673894985,
 1.1818496551780364,
 1.256060021892613,
 1.1922912062142983,
 1.1902422382130782,
 1.1992276134291726,
 1.1710757539172894,
 1.123994660195365,
 1.2214993644613943,
 1.155215069374298,
 1.1086344864348479,
 1.0910943060265557,
 1.2191511677776559,
 1.210061225791385,
 1.177381635100414,
 1.181486384213164,
 1.165494009707241,
 1.1963931772967231,
 1.2102493016491176,
 1.101845863755783,
 1.2104131731458112,
 1.2496346326865795,
 1.1918641349127161,
 1.2362974006491536,
 1.2055345356030078,
 1.2285741635823975,
 1.2335964200302294,
 1.2299260975739024,
 1.252639296531916,
 1.1816404229058095,
 1.0906166413304024,
 1.2083432826502967,
 1.198686258537757,
 1.1415695127122047,
 1.092894116614261,
 1.2066842100186415,
 1.156538986861618,
 1.2474806142885053,
 1.2187478225293684,
 1.2316920790783128,
 1.2105404142792078,
 1.2045940601752774,
 1.1231347496689397,
 1.1047593741136272,
 1.18129835095779,
 1.1835647508539222,
 1.2450528028358812,
 1.2222158604224076,
 1.2150490929276319,
 1.1816927028319475,
 1.1823015755626682,
 1.2708857606096744,
 1.1919272687522717,
 1.199215576802391,
 1.2235538374085948,
 1.2001199439086292,
 1.1730857828737784,
 1.209032518532766,
 1.240920756903906,
 1.102814033624564,
 1.218812306587527,
 1.1996553618634807,
 1.179606921083769,
 1.2017295317409378,
 1.2330407322845536,
 1.1187392156488476,
 1.225736440475797,
 1.0995456254389886,
 1.1398239919352195,
 1.2035675444496818,
 1.1586383728042269,
 1.2287334286814806,
 1.195581908342988,
 1.182475780454091,
 1.1987430360427977,
 1.216557035654513,
 1.1996494907287538,
 1.2383901831314694,
 1.1531934815518878,
 1.229216103794829,
 1.2106112336572799,
 1.1849778997346532,
 1.18237184590969,
 1.2009038458812764,
 1.0961585804850271,
 1.178040774021339,
 1.1722305560727864,
 1.2280646936758626,
 1.1730878580889061,
 1.1798127065856396,
 1.224173817391561,
 1.2065293766499958,
 1.1997898485636171,
 1.2424004246290328,
 1.1717570065002927,
 1.2338402423416157,
 1.2494056527462882,
 1.2188644637313981,
 1.2212661458082938,
 1.2339544318944837,
 1.1071211607425422,
 1.1606278890869028,
 1.2189699753534322,
 1.180272917562664,
 1.1426456950772235,
 1.0522788530258245,
 1.1829427275613456,
 1.2262188308828839,
 1.2251773195743205,
 1.1956258209753046,
 1.2114920876892714,
 1.1953916820234736,
 1.23382398473895,
 1.1582401755284804,
 1.191629137388988,
 1.2178006337369847,
 1.251136439760085,
 1.1365976380520602,
 1.174275078234959,
 1.0808087704223992,
 1.2032740733244425,
 1.2103517133973012,
 1.11326005536463,
 1.1909349869585562,
 1.2212796832585389,
 1.1075096790834102,
 1.2498229141296608,
 1.084664865732375,
 1.1683357564539953,
 1.2082937933568851,
 1.252239384886692,
 1.2241448948948157,
 1.2220195905349323,
 1.0755183739777228,
 1.2246287887655924,
 1.203941883586293,
 1.1242510612918695,
 1.2235007768884452,
 1.1730788382137691,
 1.0994391409748683,
 1.223672903798066,
 1.1273787876886823,
 1.2387058055283537,
 1.2136671563285772,
 1.204874914999746,
 1.1863124400411849,
 1.2194323539365215,
 1.139574455552127,
 1.1883768406708517,
 1.2000846688283575,
 1.1745314981161292,
 1.2216393545756357,
 1.148559186473642,
 1.1276502268015958,
 1.1678501220114077,
 1.248042556728196,
 1.1528823530190904,
 1.182349952140096,
 1.202872559373987,
 1.057656133683926,
 1.196122637100774,
 1.2031121605191817,
 1.1634951499402728,
 1.2095000735625363,
 1.1901826500944825,
 1.1705303635565636,
 1.221904684759513,
 1.2008426805755377,
 1.2191513614245515,
 1.2383835946927975,
 1.1822466263148794,
 1.2000277251766025,
 1.0675643227701521,
 1.2229772647360104,
 1.082493154489034,
 1.178347854805873,
 1.1940673459489852,
 1.1946568831787179,
 1.219277339137701,
 1.135039734235405,
 1.2539824081361624,
 1.2267246222664205,
 1.0960629129827957,
 1.2130669354862218,
 1.2300957041596126,
 1.1573830982698168,
 1.096123662648259,
 1.2477729284441184,
 1.2135638836890315,
 1.220630164390247,
 1.2162877159119596,
 1.2090167543426475,
 1.187489906720505,
 1.2275503381344637,
 1.1086754622565136,
 1.1618707919314104,
 1.1070407212315239,
 1.1923226787718677,
 1.0900666694354006,
 1.2262690661499525,
 1.2056761416930777,
 1.2458301275482253,
 1.1732441231849604,
 1.2211117817426773,
 1.1948872902367709,
 1.130818495246797,
 1.2026206008072473,
 1.2067040095784871,
 1.1913340391980174,
 1.2398675486238038,
 1.1780518996775449,
 1.1806804473198347,
 1.2154433988507445,
 1.2041310140780057,
 1.1948521569436659,
 1.1658255171990985,
 1.2146852320116623,
 1.2174547247773808,
 1.2307680369014695,
 1.1682623391256952,
 1.2188082178033945,
 1.2423527542349246,
 1.13230783361083,
 1.2097691357097797,
 1.2047969399649594,
 1.1517698102978422,
 1.2065252124817711,
 1.0985349880573572,
 1.1426104372808603,
 1.2351760150170086,
 1.1902473719724727,
 1.1791482059371399,
 1.1185800577890548,
 1.1774186347558009,
 1.2397017660770022,
 1.1932399219346395,
 1.1009298704332167,
 1.1104128735371144
]
```

**How should I plot this large data using python to better visualize the data?**

Comment: Please clarify what you are after and what's wrong with your existing plot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and common method to get a better overview about this kind of data is to calculate the [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) (mainly it to see if there are any trends). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean) for different approaches to calculate the moving average in python.

*Note 1:* You need to decide how much you want to smooth the data by setting a parameter (called `N` here). You might have to play around a little with `N` to see which value best suits your data.

*Note 2:* By calculating the moving average the length of you data changes (it gets `N-1` shorter). So the timestamp values must also be shortened.

Using the sample data from the question and choosing `N=51`:

```py
import numpy as np 

N = 51
myList_fitnessValues_ma = np.convolve(myList_fitnessValues, np.ones(N)/N, mode='valid')
myList_timestamps_ma = myList_timestamps[int((N-1)/2):-int((N-1)/2)]
                     
plt.plot(myList_timestamps_ma, myList_fitnessValues_ma)
plt.xlabel('Timestamps (seconds)')
plt.ylabel('WATT - MSU Fitness Values (moving average)')
plt.title('Evolutionary Optimization - Execution Time')
plt.show()
```

[image: Moving average for sample data]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking exactly for this.

Comment: The optimal value is 1.036. Is it possible to display the values of the x-label and y-label according to the highest and lowest values?

Comment: You mean, like [scaling the data into another range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio)? Not sure what you have in mind...

Comment: I mean I want to display the y-label values from smallest to largest values. For instance, the optimal value in the y-label range is 1.036, but there is no close value to this `optimal value (1.036 )` in the above data representation. However, the y-label starts from `1.190, 1.185, ..., 1.175, 1.170`.